# Cosets representatives of congruence subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory

I came across Shimura (1971) notes about cosets representatives of the congruence subgroups $ \Gamma_0(N) $. He firstly proves that its index in the modular group $\Gamma$ is

\begin{equation} [\Gamma : \Gamma_0(N)]=N \cdot \prod_{p|N} (1+p^{-1} ) \end{equation}

Then he comes up with a sets of cosets representatives for $\Gamma_0(N)$ in $\Gamma$ made in this way: we first choose pairs $(c,d)$ of positive integers such that

\begin{equation} (c,d)=1, \qquad d|N, \qquad 0 < c \le N/d \end{equation}

then for each pairs we fix integers $a,b$ such that $ad-bc=1$. Our list of cosets representatives is made of the matrices with such entries.

However, let us take for example $N=12$ when we know the index is 24 and thus this is the cardinality of the set of cosets representatives.
Using the rule above, I only find 22 cosets representatives, namely the ones corresponding to the following $(c,d)$ pairs: $$(1,1),(2,1),\dots,(12,1),(1,2),(3,2),(5,2),(1,3),(2,3),(4,3),(1,4),(3,4),(1,6),(1,12).$$

I also tried to run SAGE and it gives me 24 cosets representatives but they seem redundant, for example $[[1, 0] [2, 1]]$ and $[[1, 2][2, 5]]$ are listed as different cosets representatives, but

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$

and thus it seems to me that these 2 matrices belong in fact to the same coset.

Something is clearly wrong, I hope you can help me.

Comment: The missing representatives are (0,1) for the coset of 1, and (1,0).

Comment: Actually, my comment (and my now deleted answer) is incorrect. Assuming you mean the group of matrices `$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$` for which $c$ is divisible by $N$, then of course $1\in\Gamma$ is in the coset represented by $(N,1)$ (and (0,1) is just another rep for that). Moreover, $(1,0)$ and $(1,N)$ also represent the same coset.

Comment: Does everything work for prime $N?$

Comment: Yes, for prime $N$, we have that $R=Z/NZ$ is a finite field, in particular all elements are units, and it is well known that the projective line has the coset representatives $(1,1),\ldots,(1,N),(N,1)=(0,1)$.

Comment: The output by Sage is correct, I think it gives you representatives for the left quotient $\Gamma_0(N) \backslash \Gamma$.

Comment: For reference, what was wrong is that in Shimura's description, the condition $(c,d)=1$ should be replaced by $(c,d,N/d)=1$, see the answers by Max Horn and me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another attempt, this time hopefully with a correct answer. First off, the problem gets worse for e.g. N=24, where the index is 48, yet we only get 44 coset representatives.

For $N=12$, representatives for the two missing cosets are for example $(1,9)=(5,9)=(7,3)=(11,3)$ and $(1,8)=(5,4)=(7,8)=(11,4)$ (here with equality I mean that the pairs represent the same coset).

To find these, I first claim that there is a natural bijection beween $\Gamma/\Gamma_0(N)$ and the "projective line" $P^1(R)$, where $R:=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, which consists of the "1-dimensional subspaces of $R^2$". That is, subsets of $R^2$ of the form $(c,d) \cdot R^\times$ and of size $\lvert R^\times \rvert$. Indeed, it is easy to very that $\Gamma$ acts transitively (say, from the right) on $P^1(R)$, and the stabilizer of $(0,1)\cdot R^\times$ then equals $\Gamma_0(N)$. The claim follows.

Thus we just have to find representatives for the orbits $A:=(c,d)\cdot R^\times$ of $P^1(R)$. If $d$ is a unit, we can divide by $d$ and thus we certainly can choose the pairs $(c,1)$ as one type of coset representative. It remains to consider the pairs $(c,d)$ where $d$ is not a unit. Note that we may choose $1\leq c,d\leq N$ such that $gcd(c,d)=1$ (for either the gcd is invertible mod $N$, and so we can divide it out; or else it is a non-unit $x$, but then $x\cdot R^\times$ is strictly smaller than $R^\times$, and so $A$ is not an element of $P^1(R)$).

Looking at the formula you give (and attribute to Shimura), this is exactly what happens there: The element $d$ is either 1, or else $gcd(d,N)\neq 1$, in which case $d$ corresponds to a non-unit of $R$; one can in fact show that the $R^\times$-orbits (action by multiplication) on $R$ have the divisors of $N$ as representants.

However, the formula you describe is then to restrictive on what values for $c$ are used. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you a good closed formula as alternative right now, but with the above description, it is still relatively easy to compute representatives for all orbits: Let $d$ vary as described, but then do not only consider $c\leq N/d$, but rather study the orbits of $Stab_{R^\times}(d)$ on $R$ to find all possible values for $c$. In our example $N=12$, for example, the orbits of $R^\times$ on $R$ are $[ [ 0 ], [ 1, 5, 7, 11 ], [ 2, 10 ], [ 3, 9 ], [ 4, 8 ], [ 6 ] ]$. The stabilizer of e.g. $d=3$ is the subgroup of $R^\times$ containing $1$ and $5$. Its orbits on $R$ are $[ [ 0 ], [ 1, 5 ], [ 2, 10 ], [ 3 ], [ 4, 8 ], [ 6 ], [ 7, 11 ], [ 9 ] ]$. Hence we get the pairs $(1,3), (2,3), (4,3), (7,3)$ as the desired coset representatives with $d=3$. (The other values for $c$ are not allowed, as then $gcd(c,d)\neq 1$, which means that $(c,d)\cdot R^\times$ will be too small).

Answer (score 2):

(2022.03.27, edited after Tireless and hardworking's remark.)

The quotient $\Gamma_0(N) \backslash \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ (right cosets) is in bijection with the set of pairs $(c,d)$ where $c$ is a positive divisor of $N$ and $1 \leq d \leq \frac{N}{c}$ satisfies $\operatorname{gcd}(d,c,\frac{N}{c})=1$.

To get the image of a matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, first find $u \in (\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z})^\times$ such that $\gamma u \equiv \operatorname{gcd}(\gamma,N) \bmod{N}$. Then $M$ is mapped to $(c,d):=(\operatorname{gcd}(\gamma,N), \delta u \bmod{\frac{N}{c}})$. It is a good exercice to check that this gives a well-defined and bijective map.

To get an explicit matrix representative associated to $(c,d)$, first find an integer $1 \leq \delta \leq N$ such that $\delta \equiv d \mod{\frac{N}{c}}$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(\delta,c)=1$, then find integers $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $\alpha \delta- \beta c=1$, and you get your representative $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ c & \delta \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Let $N=9$, and let $M_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$, and let $M_2=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 9C & D \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_0(9)$, where $D \equiv 2 \mod{3}$. No matter if we consider left cosets or right cosets, then the map is not well defined, because $M_1M_2=\begin{pmatrix} A+9c & B+D \\ 3A+36C & 3B+4D \end{pmatrix}$, and $M_2M_1=\begin{pmatrix} A+3B & A+4B \\ 9C+3D & 9C+4D \end{pmatrix}$, and we have: 

$$M_1 \mapsto (3, 1),$$ 
$$M_1M_2 \mapsto (3, 2),$$ 
$$M_2M_1 \mapsto (3, 2),$$ 

so two different represntatives do not send to a unique element.

Comment: @Tirelessandhardworking I see, the definition of the map $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix} \mapsto (c,d)$ is incorrect. One should first find $u \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$ such that $\gamma u \equiv \mathrm{gcd}(\gamma,N) \bmod{N}$, and multiply $\delta$ by $u$ accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. The map is impressive and the excercise was interesting. I verified that the map is well-defined, injective and surjective. I read also the answer by user "Max Horn", and now I can see some relations between his answer and your answer (the relation about "projective line", and the role of $u$ and $(c, d)$), but yet **I can not understand where the "congruence mod $\frac{N}{c}$ over $d$" emerged form?**

Comment: @Tirelessandhardworking I think I came up with the formula starting with the description of $\Gamma_1(N) \backslash \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ as the set of pairs $(u,v) \in (\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z})^2$ such that $u,v$ generate $\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z}$, which is easier. Then one can work out the orbit a given pair $(u,v)$ under $(\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z})^\times$. But this doesn't really give an intuition. Anyway, thank you very much for pointing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the time you've spent to me. I appreciate that. Finally I found the "correspondence" between your answer and his answer, and that was just a very simple congruence excercise. I think I understood everything. Thanks for everything, specially for your kindness and your generousity dear Francois Brunault.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to "what is wrong with Shimura", but check out
http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/09-19-03/index.html and the referred to work by Helena Verrill...

Comment: The link is now broken. Just for the people who also have this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As Max points out in his answer, one is just looking for a complete list of (representatives
for) elements of the projective line $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z})$. Here are some maybe useful observations:

(*) If $\gcd(N,M) = 1$ the natural map $\phi:\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/NM\mathbf{Z}) \to
\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z}) \times \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/M\mathbf{Z})$
is bijective.

If one has an element of $([a:b],[c:d]) \in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/N\mathbf{Z}) \times \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/M\mathbf{Z})$ in order to find $[e:f] = \phi^{-1}(([a:b],[c:d])$
one just needs to solve the congruences $e \equiv a \pmod N$, $e \equiv c \pmod M$, $f \equiv b \pmod N$ and $f \equiv d \pmod M$ for $e,f \in \mathbf{Z}$.

This reduces the problem to the case where $N = p^\ell$ is a power of a prime number $p$.
Here one observes:

(**) $|\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/p^\ell\mathbf{Z})| = (p+1)p^{\ell-1}$, and a complete list of representatives is as follows:
{$[1:x] \mid x \in p\mathbf{Z}/{p^\ell}\mathbf{Z}$} together with
{$[(a + p^\ell\mathbf{Z})+y:1] \mid 0 \le a < p, y \in p\mathbf{Z}/{p^\ell}\mathbf{Z}$}.

From this point of view, one sees the problem(s) with the original list of representatives provided by the OP; e.g., in the list (1,1),(2,1),...,(12,1),(1,2),(3,2),(5,2),(1,3),(2,3),(4,3),(1,4),(3,4),(1,6),(1,12) there are only three pairs (e,f) for which

$$\phi([e:f]) = ([1:1],?) \in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}) \times \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})$$

-- namely (1,1), (5,1), and (9,1) --
and only three pairs (e,f) for which

$$\phi([e:f]) = ([1:0],?) \in \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}) \times \mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})$$

-- namely (1,4), (3,4) and (1,12) --
and in each case there should be 4 = $|\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})|$ such pairs. Max's answer listed the missing pairs, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, summing up: the algorithm described in my first message is wrong, but the algorithm Max describes works, even though a closed, nice formula is not available (yet). Maybe one can obtain it by looking for different types of representatives, like SAGE does.
I checked out the link Igor gives and the algorithm described for constructing a fundamental domain works also for our purpose but is very "computational" while i was looking for something easier, something a human could do much faster than computing lots of matrices products. I also checked the Kulkarni's paper Verrill refers to, but it is of no help.